# How to fit a long array in IEEE Access Latex two column template?

Tags: overleaf, two-column, arrays, ieeeaccess

I am currently writing in an IEEE Access Latex format. The work I am doing involves long arrays which I am facing difficulty facing in a single column. The arrays tend to overlap with the text in the next column.

(Array overlapping with text. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yyFR.jpg)

Here are the arrays:

```
 $H_\mathbb{\mathbb{P}}
=${\scriptsize$\left\{\begin{matrix}{c}H_{\widehat{p}_1}=\{ \langle
\varrho_1,([0.3,0.5],[0.1,0.5]),(0.4,0.6)\rangle, \langle
\varrho_2,([0.3,0.4],[0.1,0.5]),(0.4,0.5)\rangle, \langle \varrho_3,([0.2,0.6],[0.1,0.4]),(0.3,0.6))\rangle \},\\
H_{\widehat{p}_2}=\{ \langle
\varrho_1,([0.1,0.4],[0.4,0.6]),(0.2,0.7)\rangle, \langle
\varrho_2,([0.2,0.4],[0.5,0.6]),(0.1,0.4)\rangle, \langle \varrho_3,([0.3,0.8],[0.1,0.2]),(0.6,0.1)\rangle \},\\
H_{\widehat{p}_3}=\{ \langle
\varrho_1,([0.2,0.6],[0.1,0.3]),(0.2,0.6)\rangle, \langle
\varrho_2,([0.2,0.4],[0.1,0.4]),(0.3,0.5)\rangle, \langle \varrho_3,([0.1,0.2],[0.3,0.8]),(0.3,0.5)\rangle\},\\
H_{\widehat{p}_4}=\{ \langle
\varrho_1,([0.1,0.4],[0.3,0.6]),(0.1,0.8)\rangle,\langle
\varrho_2,([0.1,0.5],[0.1,0.3]),(0.3,0.5)\rangle, \langle \varrho_3,([0.2,0.3],[0.2,0.7]),(0.2,0.4)\rangle \}\\
                   \end{matrix}
                 \right \}$


\begin{center}
$I_\mathbb{\mathbb{P}}
=${\scriptsize$\left\{\begin{array}{c}H_{\widehat{p}_1}=\{ \langle
\varrho_1,([0.2,0.7],[0.1,0.2]),(0.3,0.5)\rangle, \langle
\varrho_2,([0.3,0.6],[0.2,0.4]),(0.4,0.6)\rangle, \langle \varrho_3,([0.4,0.5],[0.2,0.4]),(0.6,0.3))\rangle \},\\
H_{\widehat{p}_2}=\{ \langle
\varrho_1,([0.1,0.5],[0.3,0.5]),(0.5,0.4)\rangle, \langle
\varrho_2,([0.2,0.4],[0.5,0.6]),(0.1,0.9)\rangle, \langle \varrho_3,([0.2,0.6],[0.1,0.3]),(0.5,0.4)\rangle \},\\
H_{\widehat{p}_3}=\{ \langle
\varrho_1,([0.6,0.8],[0.1,0.2]),(0.4,0.5)\rangle, \langle
\varrho_2,([0.1,0.6],[0.1,0.3]),(0.2,0.8)\rangle, \langle \varrho_3,([0.1,0.3],[0.2,0.7]),(0.2,0.4)\rangle\},\\
H_{\widehat{p}_4}=\{ \langle
\varrho_1,([0.3,0.4],[0.5,0.6]),(0.6,0.3)\rangle,\langle
\varrho_2,([0.7,0.8],[0.1,0.2]),(0.7,0.2)\rangle, \langle \varrho_3,([0.6,0.7],[0.2,0.3]),(0.1,0.5)\rangle \}\\
                   \end{array}
                 \right \}$}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
$J_\mathbb{\mathbb{P}}
=${$\left\{\begin{array}{c}H_{\widehat{p}_1}=\{ \langle
\varrho_1,([0.2,0.5],[0.1,0.4]),(0.6,0.2)\rangle, \langle
\varrho_2,([0.1,0.3],[0.2,0.7]),(0.7,0.1)\rangle, \langle \varrho_3,([0.5,0.8],[0.1,0.2]),(0.9,0.1))\rangle \},\\
H_{\widehat{p}_2}=\{ \langle
\varrho_1,([0.4,0.5],[0.1,0.3]),(0.6,0.3)\rangle, \langle
\varrho_2,([0.3,0.6],[0.2,0.4]),(0.2,0.7)\rangle, \langle \varrho_3,([0.4,0.6],[0.2,0.3]),(0.2,0.8)\rangle \},\\
H_{\widehat{p}_3}=\{ \langle
\varrho_1,([0.3,0.8],[0.1,0.2]),(0.3,0.6)\rangle, \langle
\varrho_2,([0.1,0.5],[0.3,0.5]),(0.3,0.4)\rangle, \langle \varrho_3,([0.2,0.4],[0.1,0.3]),(0.4,0.3)\rangle\},\\
H_{\widehat{p}_4}=\{ \langle
\varrho_1,([0.3,0.6],[0.1,0.3]),(0.1,0.5)\rangle,\langle
\varrho_2,([0.4,0.5],[0.2,0.4]),(0.7,0.2)\rangle, \langle \varrho_3,([0.7,0.8],[0.1,0.2]),(0.8,0.1)\rangle \}\\
                   \end{array}
                 \right \}$}
\end{center}

\noindent Now, a reference set is used for comparison of the alternatives so the closest to the ideal alternative is selected. Assume the properties of an ideal storage facility for cement are recorded in the form of an n-tuple to see the 
highest level of n-tuple compliance with $H_\mathbb{\mathbb{P}}$, $I_\mathbb{\mathbb{P}}$ and $J_\mathbb{\mathbb{P}}$.
For this purpose, a list is compiled with different storage options they have currently available out of which their aim is to the select the closest to the ideal option. Most of the data for considering the similarity between the presented options is available in the form of human intuition allowing room for uncertainty which is best dealt using fuzzy structures. The list in the form of CIFHSS is shown below:

\begin{center}

   $$ R_\mathbb{\mathbb{P}}
={\left\{\begin{array}{c}H_{\widehat{p}_1}=\{ \langle
\varrho_1,([0.1,0.3],[0.2,0.5]),(0.6,0.3)\rangle, \langle
\varrho_2,([0.5,0.6],[0.3,0.4]),(0.2,0.7)\rangle, \langle \varrho_3,([0.3,0.8],[0.1,0.2]),(0.2,0.7))\rangle \},\\
H_{\widehat{p}_2}=\{ \langle
\varrho_1,([0.3,0.6],[0.2,0.3]),(0.8,0.1)\rangle, \langle
\varrho_2,([0.1,0.4],[0.2,0.6]),(0.3,0.5)\rangle, \langle M\varrho_3,([0.4,0.5],[0.3,0.4]),(0.3,0.6)\rangle \},\\
H_{\widehat{p}_3}=\{ \langle
\varrho_1,([0.1,0.6],[0.2,0.3]),(0.3,0.5)\rangle, \langle
\varrho_2,([0.2,0.5],[0.3,0.5]),(0.1,0.4)\rangle, \langle \varrho_3,([0.1,0.8],[0.1,0.2]),(0.2,0.7)\rangle\},\\
H_{\widehat{p}_4}=\{ \langle
\varrho_1,([0.4,0.5],[0.2,0.4]),(0.1,0.8)\rangle,\langle
\varrho_2,([0.6,0.7],[0.1,0.3]),(0.7,0.1)\rangle, \langle \varrho_3,([0.5,0.8],[0.1,0.2]),(0.4,0.6)\rangle \}\\
                   \end{array}
                 \right \}}$$
                 \end{center}
```

Now, I have also attached a link that will direct anyone to the IEEE Access template (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ieee-access-latex-template/cdxrhtbjgszv).

Please help me adjust these arrays either in the center of the page of in a single column.

Thank you

I have tried changing the sizes of the arrays and also tried to break the arrays but both of the things didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ and which document-level options you employ.

Comment: Please also explain the purpose of the frequent doubling up on the `\mathbb` directives, as in `\mathbb{\mathbb{P}}`.

Comment: Currently, I am using \documentclass{ieeeaccess}, as for the document level options, I wrote the arrays below the \begin{section} so I believe that would be normal text. Secondly, the use of \mathbb is because of the symbols I am using. It is necessary to add the command as its not giving me the results I require without it.

Comment: I tried to remove the double directives (\mathbb) as advised and the output is the same. Thank you for pointing that out. Not sure why I put them there in the first place.

Comment: You can put 2 column wide equations into figure* or table*, or create a new float type just for equations.  Note that the equations numbers are assigned when the float is created, so you might want a separate counter and protocol.

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

I'm afraid your arrays are simply much too big to be placed in a single column. I've cleaned up the code of the array; its width is more than twice the value of `\columnwidth`. Even after switching to `\tiny` -- for a 50% linear reduction in font size -- the array's width still exceeds `\columnwidth` by far.

I think your only choice is to come up with a radically different approach to displaying the contents of the arrays. E.g., can you break down the components of each row into smaller parts and then show these components individually, instead of showing one long and complicated row?

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{IEEEaccess} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-8] % a few lines of filler text
\[
H_{\mathbb{P}} =
\begin{Bmatrix}
H_{\hat{p}_1}=
\langle \varrho_1,([0.3,0.5],[0.1,0.5]),(0.4,0.6)\rangle, 
\langle \varrho_2,([0.3,0.4],[0.1,0.5]),(0.4,0.5)\rangle, 
\langle \varrho_3,([0.2,0.6],[0.1,0.4]),(0.3,0.6)\rangle,\\
H_{\hat{p}_2}=
\langle \varrho_1,([0.1,0.4],[0.4,0.6]),(0.2,0.7)\rangle, 
\langle \varrho_2,([0.2,0.4],[0.5,0.6]),(0.1,0.4)\rangle, 
\langle \varrho_3,([0.3,0.8],[0.1,0.2]),(0.6,0.1)\rangle,\\
H_{\hat{p}_3}=
\langle \varrho_1,([0.2,0.6],[0.1,0.3]),(0.2,0.6)\rangle, 
\langle \varrho_2,([0.2,0.4],[0.1,0.4]),(0.3,0.5)\rangle, 
\langle \varrho_3,([0.1,0.2],[0.3,0.8]),(0.3,0.5)\rangle,\\
H_{\hat{p}_4}=
\langle \varrho_1,([0.1,0.4],[0.3,0.6]),(0.1,0.8)\rangle,
\langle \varrho_2,([0.1,0.5],[0.1,0.3]),(0.3,0.5)\rangle, 
\langle \varrho_3,([0.2,0.3],[0.2,0.7]),(0.2,0.4)\rangle \\
\end{Bmatrix}
\]
\lipsum[1][9-12] % more filler text

\bigskip
\tiny
\lipsum[1][1-8] % a few lines of filler text
\[
H_{\mathbb{P}} =
\begin{Bmatrix}
H_{\hat{p}_1}=
\langle \varrho_1,([0.3,0.5],[0.1,0.5]),(0.4,0.6)\rangle, 
\langle \varrho_2,([0.3,0.4],[0.1,0.5]),(0.4,0.5)\rangle, 
\langle \varrho_3,([0.2,0.6],[0.1,0.4]),(0.3,0.6)\rangle,\\
H_{\hat{p}_2}=
\langle \varrho_1,([0.1,0.4],[0.4,0.6]),(0.2,0.7)\rangle, 
\langle \varrho_2,([0.2,0.4],[0.5,0.6]),(0.1,0.4)\rangle, 
\langle \varrho_3,([0.3,0.8],[0.1,0.2]),(0.6,0.1)\rangle,\\
H_{\hat{p}_3}=
\langle \varrho_1,([0.2,0.6],[0.1,0.3]),(0.2,0.6)\rangle, 
\langle \varrho_2,([0.2,0.4],[0.1,0.4]),(0.3,0.5)\rangle, 
\langle \varrho_3,([0.1,0.2],[0.3,0.8]),(0.3,0.5)\rangle,\\
H_{\hat{p}_4}=
\langle \varrho_1,([0.1,0.4],[0.3,0.6]),(0.1,0.8)\rangle,
\langle \varrho_2,([0.1,0.5],[0.1,0.3]),(0.3,0.5)\rangle, 
\langle \varrho_3,([0.2,0.3],[0.2,0.7]),(0.2,0.4)\rangle \\
\end{Bmatrix}
\]
\lipsum[1][9-12] % more filler text

\EOD
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comment. I think you may be best off placing the four large expressions in a `table` in landscape mode on a page all by themselves. Then, refer to the objects from within the text.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{IEEEaccess} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-6] % filler text

\afterpage{ % defer execution until start of next page
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\caption{Some tuples}

\begin{align*}
H_{\mathbb{P}} &=
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{aligned}
c H_{\hat{p}_1} &=
\langle \varrho_1,([0.3,0.5],[0.1,0.5]),(0.4,0.6)\rangle, 
\langle \varrho_2,([0.3,0.4],[0.1,0.5]),(0.4,0.5)\rangle, 
\langle \varrho_3,([0.2,0.6],[0.1,0.4]),(0.3,0.6)\rangle,\\
H_{\hat{p}_2} &=
\langle \varrho_1,([0.1,0.4],[0.4,0.6]),(0.2,0.7)\rangle, 
\langle \varrho_2,([0.2,0.4],[0.5,0.6]),(0.1,0.4)\rangle, 
\langle \varrho_3,([0.3,0.8],[0.1,0.2]),(0.6,0.1)\rangle,\\
H_{\hat{p}_3} &=
\langle \varrho_1,([0.2,0.6],[0.1,0.3]),(0.2,0.6)\rangle, 
\langle \varrho_2,([0.2,0.4],[0.1,0.4]),(0.3,0.5)\rangle, 
\langle \varrho_3,([0.1,0.2],[0.3,0.8]),(0.3,0.5)\rangle,\\
H_{\hat{p}_4} &=
\langle \varrho_1,([0.1,0.4],[0.3,0.6]),(0.1,0.8)\rangle,
\langle \varrho_2,([0.1,0.5],[0.1,0.3]),(0.3,0.5)\rangle, 
\langle \varrho_3,([0.2,0.3],[0.2,0.7]),(0.2,0.4)\rangle \ 
\end{aligned}
\end{Bmatrix} \\[3\jot] % a bit more vertical separation
I_{\mathbb{P}} &= 
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{aligned}
H_{\hat{p}_1} &= \dots \\
H_{\hat{p}_2} &= \dots \\
H_{\hat{p}_3} &= \dots \\
H_{\hat{p}_4} &= \dots \ 
\end{aligned}
\end{Bmatrix} \\[3\jot]
J_{\mathbb{P}} &= 
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{aligned}
H_{\hat{p}_1} &= \dots \\
H_{\hat{p}_2} &= \dots \\
H_{\hat{p}_3} &= \dots \\
H_{\hat{p}_4} &= \dots \ 
\end{aligned}
\end{Bmatrix} \\[3\jot]
R_{\mathbb{P}} &= 
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{aligned}
H_{\hat{p}_1} &= \dots \\
H_{\hat{p}_2} &= \dots \\
H_{\hat{p}_3} &= \dots \\
H_{\hat{p}_4} &= \dots \ 
\end{aligned}
\end{Bmatrix} 
\end{align*}

\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\clearpage
}

\lipsum[7-19] % more filler text

\EOD
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to optimize the code. This is the problem that i was facing. I tried reducing the text size to \tiny but no luck. Is there a way that the text in the column right next to the text moves down so that the array displays in the middle of the page and the text goes above or below it?

Comment: @HarisSaeed - Speaking for myself, I think that your suggested layout would actually look absolutely awful. Andi it would only work if the big expressions happen to occur in the left-hand column, no? Sorry for being harsh. I think that you should be planning on is to put the equations onto a page in landscape mode.

Comment: @HarisSaeed - Please see the addendum I posted, in which I show how to display the big objects in landscape mode, on a page all by themselves.

Comment: Okay, I'll review the addendum you posted. Last night, I was trying out some new ways to display the information and I finally got an acceptable illustration from my supervisor. I converted the array into a table as you suggested and now it looks fine. Thank you for your guidance.